# restrict user to enter number in 00.000 format

Tags: javascript

I need user to enter only 2 digit and 3 decimal values in input. i do have code with regex which works to test logic, but its not working with regex.replace()

please help me to use regex replace to replace non match character with blank.

i tried with only numbers and it works with keyup event. but not working with decimal."

```
$(document).on('keyup','.numbersOnly', function() {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,'');
});
$(document).on('keyup','#inputBox', function() {
    var regex = /[^\d{1,2}(\.\d{1,3})?$]/g;
    this.value = this.value.replace(regex,'');
});
```

if user enter 100, last zero need to replace with '' from regex.

if user enter 4.1235, last decimal(5) need to replace with "" from regex

Comment: I think there are many more edge cases you are not even covering.  I vote for accepting any number and then rounding to your desired precision.

Comment: basically i am looking for this logic for interest rate. So user can enter only xx.xxx format only.

Comment: You are going to need to maintain state for the last valid entry, and then replace the current input with that should the regex fail.  Warning: this can be a can of worms.

Answer (score 0):

You are using regex incorrectly. The `[]` and the characters between them are used to match a single character. `[^\d.]` matches any single character except digits and dot.